# Call async functions successively with Observables

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

I need to call async functions successively meaning that the async function is inside a loop but to call the next function, I need the previous one to finish. Here is a code example:

```
for(var index in array){
   myAsyncFunction(arg, (newArg) =>{
      // use newArg for the successive myAsyncFunction calls
   })
}
```

Each myAsyncFunction as to wait the previous one to end so it can call it with the new argument.

I did that using `$q.when` with angular 1 but don't know how to do this with Rxjs

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap), or `concatMapTo()`. Don't have working example, hope docs can help you...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with `array.reduce`.

```
array.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => {
  return prev.then((arg) => {
    return myAsyncFunction(arg);
  });
}, arg)
```

*I don't really understand what `arg` and `newArg` are in your example therefor my code might not be exactly what you want.*

You can find more details in

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question but here goes :)
If using Observables they are not initiated unless something subscribes to them.
And if i understand you want to load something and when its loaded make new arguments then pass them into same loading function to load another resource.

This code is mostly teoretical as i havent tested it. As you can see it will call itself again once the first call is done and do so untill we decide that we want to interupt (in my eg. we could set newArg to true and in that if statement check for that) or encounter some error.

```
    private getSmth(arg): Observable {
        // do something with arg
        return this.http.get(url)
          .map(this.extractData) // function to handle response
          .catch(this.handleError); // function to handle errors
      }

    public loadSmth(arg): void {
        if (arg has ending requirements) {
          console.log('THE END');
          return;
        }
        this.getSmth(arg)
          .subscribe(data => {
            // do something with data maybe generate new args
            this.loadSmth(newArgs);
          }, error => this.error = error);
      }
```